# Changing button image when another button is clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, button, imageview

I'm facing a problem in xcode, in one of my view controllers i have two buttons, when one of them is clicked (`appleBtn`) the second button's (`topMenu1Btn`) image should change

I created an outlet for both buttons, an action for the applebtn when clicked

```
- (IBAction)HandleBtnClick:(id)sender {
    self.topMenu1Btn.imageView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.jpg"]
}
```

the thing is the imageview is read-only
is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)HandleBtnClick:(id)sender
{
    [self.topMenu1Btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to set the image for the button.

```
[self.topMenu1Bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

If you want the background image use `setBackgroundImage:` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.topMenu1Btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or

```
[self.topMenu1Bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

If you use the second method then make sure that the frame of image matches with the button

Make sure that Button type is Custom

Answer (score 0):

- (IBAction)HandleBtnClick:(id)sender {
  self.topMenu1Btn.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.jpg"]
  }

You can't modify the imageview, but you can modify the image in it ;)